# How to use different accounts on different Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I have two different accounts for Stack Exchange.

One account for [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) (entering E-Mail + password), and another for [the science fiction site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) via (also E-Mail + password, no Google or Facebook connection). I don't want the two connected for... reasons.

When I log into Stack Overflow, *Science Fiction & Fantasy* prompts me to connect my account to the site, instead of offering the option to use the other account.

Can I log in with two different accounts on different Stack Exchange sites at the same time, and if yes, how (with the same browser)?

Comment: Ah yes... its a duplicate :\